# Will a firmware update/change erase Canon's service center lens calibration settings?

Tags: lens, canon, canon-60d, repair, color-management

Since it's pretty cheap in Korea, I sent all my prime lenses and my new Canon 60D to be calibrated at the local Canon service center so they can be "matched" to the body.

If I install a newer updated Canon firmware, or update to the Magic Lantern alternative firmware in the future, will I lose all of the service center settings?

Also, is the adjustment made mainly in the lenses and/or the body? I can't get a clear answer on this online. My Korean isn't so great so I can't get a good answer from the service center either.

Comment: What a great and novel questions. I wonder if the answer differs for other makers and models?

Answer (score 2):

Not on the 5D II or 1D III according to this: http://forums.dpreview.com/forums/readflat.asp?forum=1032&message=30722960&changemode=1

Before there was microadjustment in firmware Canon would calibrate the lens and/or bodies by replacing the metal mounts. Perhaps (hopefully!) this is still how it's done.

Magic Lantern doesn't wipe your settings.

Comment: Oh, if anybody is wondering about prices, it's about $20-30 for each lens in Korea. Probaly cheaper in some thirdworld countries. They may say the process takes a week or two, but if you tell them you have an important shoot; they'll speed up the process.